# Android Room combining the result of N queries into a live data list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

I have a room database setup and I want to query that database N number of times and combine the results of each query into a live data array to display back to the user.

I'm pretty sure I want to be using `MediatorLiveData` but every example online has a predefined amount of live data sources it is combining.

I have the following setup:

*petDao*

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pet_table WHERE name LIKE :petName")
    fun getPetsByPetName(petName: String): LiveData<Pet>
```

*petRepository*

```
    fun getPetsByPetName(petNames: List<String>): LiveData<List<Pet>> {
        for (petName: String in petNames) {
            val pets = petDao.getPetsByPetName(petName)
            // Combine into one live list of pets
        }
    }
```

Comment: Personally, I would use [`Flow` and `zip()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html), or perhaps RxJava's `Observable` and its `zip()`. You can write a `zip()` with N items for `LiveData`, but this is the sort of situation that causes me to steer developers towards coroutines and RxJava, with `LiveData` handling "the last mile" for delivering results to the UI layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this in your DAO?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM pet_table WHERE name IN (:petNames)")
fun getPetsByPetName(petNames: List<String>): LiveData<List<Pet>>
```

It should work with a list of up to 999 arguments. (not sure if the parameter has to be an array, or if the list is fine)

> As an extension over SQLite bind arguments, Room supports binding a
> list of parameters to the query. At runtime, Room will build the
> correct query to have matching number of bind arguments depending on
> the number of items in the method parameter.
> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query

To me it seems more appropriate for the example you've given.

Comment: Excellent didn't even know this was a possibility, thank you!